# How to remove all String text before equals ('=') sign Java

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to parse a string so I can build an XML document.

I have:

```
String value = "path=/Some/Xpath/Here";
```

I've parsed it this way:

```
private void parseXpath() {
    String s = "path=/Some/Xpath/Here";

    String[] tokens = s.split("/");
    for(String t: tokens){
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

output:

```
path=
Some
Xpath
Here
```

How can I remove "path=" altogether? I want just the values from xpath?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the responses.

How can I make this method into one which returns String[],

Example:

```
private String[] parseXpath(String s) {

String[] tokens = s.replaceFirst(".*=", "").split("/");
   for(String t: tokens){
      System.out.println(t);
   }
   return tokens;
}
```

My output is:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@413849df
```

How can I make it return me array of strings?

Comment: it already returns a array of string, but you cant just throw it into System.out.println(...); that would just print its object-id. you need to iterate the array to print its contents

Comment: Or use `System.out.println( Arrays.toString( arr ) )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do replace before splitting.

```
String[] tokens = s.replaceFirst(".*=", "").split("/");
```

This would give you an empty element at first because it would do splitting on the first forward slash after replacing.

**or**

```
String[] tokens = s.replaceFirst(".*=/", "").split("/");
```

But if you remove all the chars upto the `=` along with the first forward slash will give you the desired output.

Comment: replacing *= with "" will replace it with an empty line, how could it be no empty line

Comment: `".*="` would match all the chars upto the equal sign.

Comment: I edited my question, how could I make it into a method returning a value

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString()` method.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I'm new to this stuff

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is tagged with `regex` here is a solution using `substring`

```
    String[] tokens = s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 1).split("/");
```

or

```
    String[] tokens = s.substring(s.indexOf("=/") + 1).split("/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
private void parseXpath() {
    String s = "path=/Some/Xpath/Here";
    s = s.replace("path=","");

    String[] tokens = s.split("/");
    for(String t: tokens){
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Also you can avoid removing it at all, if you get `path=/Some/Xpath/Here` by other regex, use lookbehind instead of exact matching:

```
(?<=path=)[^\\,]*
```

you should get just `/Some/Xpath/Here`.

EDIT
If you want to print array as String, use static method `Arrays.toString(yourArray);`

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking into performance you should avoid usage of split since it uses regular-expressions which is a bit oversized for such a simple problem.
if you just want to remove "path=" and you are sure that your string always starts that way you could go with the following:

```
String s = "path=/Some/Xpath/Here";
String prefix = "path=";
String result = s.substring(prefix.length);
```